# Al insertar un valor numérico, el programa lo detecta como minúscula y número

Tags: java

El problema que tengo es que cuando inserto un valor numérico, mi programa me lo detecta como minúscula y número. No se me ocurre la solución.

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class letraynumero{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char valor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un valor:").charAt(0);

        if (Character.isDigit(valor)) { //Si detecta que insertaste un digito ,es true
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Usted inserto un numero"+valor);
    
        }

        if (Character.isUpperCase(valor)) { //Es un true false,Si la letra esta masyuscula devuelve un true

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Es una letra masyusucla"+valor);
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Es una letra miscunla"+ valor);
        }
    }//main
}//class
```

Answer (score 0):

debes usar else despues de declarar un if en caso de que no cumpla el boleano isDigit

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    
    public class option{
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    
    char valor =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite un valor:").charAt(0);
    
    
    if(Character.isDigit(valor)){//Si detecta que insertaste un digito ,es true 
    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Usted inserto un numero "+valor);
    
    }
    
    else if(Character.isUpperCase(valor)){//Es un true false,Si la letra esta masyuscula devuelve un true
    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Es una letra mayuscula "+ valor);
    } else{
    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Es una letra minuscula " +  valor);
    }
    
    
    
    
    }}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias en verdad